# Cloud foundry: configure JVM heap size and pagefile size

Tags: cloud-foundry

What do I do in order to increase JVM heap and paging file size for Cloud Foundry hosted application, while keeping main memory allocation to its VM still small?

We have a Cloud Foundry hosted Java application which, under certain occasional circumstances, needs to buffer a large amount of data in the JVM heap. The data is an array of independent objects processed more or less sequentially and independently, so application's working set (physical memory actually needed at any given time, without excessive paging) can still be small, as data access pattern makes virtual memory thrashing a non-issue.

By default, if I allocate X GB to the application in its CF deployment manifest, this request results in JVM heap of size slightly than X, and paging file sized X, e.g. 2 GB allocation to the application in the manifest file would yield 1.5 GB JVM heap and 2 GB paging file.

How can I request to allocate 2 GB of physical RAM for the CF VM, 30 GB JVM heap and 40 GB paging file?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't totally make sense.  The total memory profile of your application will include the heap size.  If you want a 30G heap then you're going to need a memory limit for your application that's greater than 30G, so it can include the heap plus all the other bits of memory that the JVM needs (metaspace, thread stacks, etc..).  In a VM or on your laptop maybe you could get around that by relying on swap space, but apps running on Cloud Foundry are not given swap space so that is not an option.

Comment: [> apps running on Cloud Foundry are not given swap space]

Is this indeed the case? 

Does CF documentation make it explicit some place that CF hosts applications as in-memory only?

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs about it, but if you look at the configuration an app container you should see it's set to not allow use of swap space.